# Submit handler post succeeds but done function does not trigger

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm an AJAX newbie and I have a very simple Arduino web server I am trying to contact and have the returned results update a div on my page. For now the server side form handler is just trying to get a simple "Hello world" back to the client. I know the server is sending the "Hello world" because I see that if I don't block the default, but of course it shows up on a new page instead of in the div like I want. I put some instrumentation code in between the post and the done functions to make sure that the post appears to succeed.
My server side handler c++ code looks something like:

```
    web_server.send_error_code(200);
    web_server.send_content_type("text/plain");
    web_server.end_headers();
    Client& client = web_server.get_client();
    client.println(F("Hello world"));
```

The html test page body (taken from the jquery submit api example) looks like:

```
    <form id="testForm" action="//192.168.1.177/test">
      <input type="submit" value="Test">
    </form>
    <!-- the results will be rendered inside this div -->
    <div id="result">This is the div</div>
    <script language="javascript">

      // Attach a submit handler to the form
      $( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();

        $( "#result" ).append( " Click"); // just to see we made it here

        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var $form = $( this ),
        url = "http://192.168.1.177/test";

        var posting = $.post( url );

        $( "#result" ).append( " Clack:"); // just instrumenting the code

        // Put the results in a div
        posting.done(function( data ) {
        //    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
        $( "#result" ).append( data );
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Post resuls!";
        });
      });

      // sanity check that the div can be changed at page load!
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Ho Ho Ho!";
      $( "#result" ).append( " Green Giant");

    </script>
```

Notice that regardless of the data, right now the code is simply trying to update the result div if that posting.done() function would just trigger!

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
var posting = $.post( url );

    $( "#result" ).append( " Clack:"); // just instrumenting the code

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function( data ) {
    //    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).append( data );
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Post resuls!";
    });
```

write this:

```
$.post( url, function(data){
   //var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
   $( "#result" ).append( data );
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Post resuls!";
});
```

also I think you need to send some data to the url in order to get something back, if not then this will do.